# How to join always the same room in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to make a chat app using socket.io, what I do is to create a room with only two people, if the room has two people already another one is created and so on, my problem is let's say you joined room 10 but you refresh the web page so it disconnects you from the room and another person disconnects from room 2 so when you're looking for an empty room you'll join 2 and not 10, I can't just use a constant as a name because I need to create another one dynamically every time one is full.

Comment: Your logic of connecting to rooms is a bit strange.... One slot empty - therefore put a person in? Like some "talk to random strangers?" What's the life-span of a *Room*? Does the room dies when there's no-one in? Or waits idle for two persons to join? Or I'm not getting your question right... you want to join again the same room you were before?

Comment: Yes, I'm making a chatbot so when a person joins the room it will join the chatbot and talk to it but if the person refreshes the web page for some reason it will join another room if there's one empty before, because rooms are created from 1 to n and it puts you in the first room with one slot available (I check one by one if one is available), so if another person already finished talking to the bot it will disconnect and if you refresh your browser you'll join the first room available previous than yours.

Answer (score 0):

You could **store** into [`window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) a room name or number that the user is joined to.
On page refresh, check if there's any value in localStorage, if yes, use that value as your **namespace**

https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

```
let roomID = localStorage.roomID; // Try to get the ID from localStorage

if ( !roomID ) { // no ID found? Create room and store ID to localStorage
  // CREATE A NEW ROOM ID (someGeneratedRoomID) <<< YOUR LOGIC HERE
  roomID = localStorage.roomID = someGeneratedRoomID; // Store it
} 

// Connect
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.join( roomID );
});

// Talk
io.to( roomID ).emit('some event');
```